# Deadlock with System.out.println and a suspended thread

Tags: java, deadlock

The following code causes a deadlock on my OSX Mavericks, I do not see the "resuming" string printed so expecting that to be the reason. I understand suspend, resume may cause deadlocks but didn't expect it to be so simple to get there.

Any obvious reasons why?

Java version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

```
class TestThread {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() { 
                while (!isInterrupted()) { 
                    System.out.println("looping");
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.suspend();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("resuming");
        t.resume();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `t` specifically?

Answer (score 3):

I has just read a book, and know why it makes deadlock.`System.out.println()` method is a `synchronized` method, here is its code:

```
/**
 * Prints a String and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>String</code> to be printed.
 */
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

so when the thread t is `suspend`ing, it maybe run into the `println` method, and lock the `PrintStream` instance, so when the main thread runs `System.out.println("resuming");`, the main thread will be blocked.
chang your code to this:

```
    //System.out.println("resuming");
    t.resume();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    t.interrupt();
    System.out.println("end");
```

you will get it normal, hope to help you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `suspend` and `resume` are deprecated, the compiler is telling you not to use them. Expect the unexpected.

Now, you're spamming the console with "looping" as fast as possible, so "resuming" is getting spammed off screen. So you never see it, and it leaves the buffer of the console.

If I comment out the printing of "looping", or print in intervals of 500 milliseconds, I can see "resuming" just fine.

Comment: Thanks for formatting my code so it is readable. 
I understand these functions should'nt be used, but was curious how it could deadlock if that is what I am seeeing.

Does your process end with the System.out.println("resuming") call present? 

I also piped the output to another file for examination and do not see the "resuming" string there.

Mine doesn't making me believe there is some sort of deadlock there.

Comment: @RakeshIyer Well, yes, I see "resuming" on the console. But, ```suspend``` and ```resume``` both call functions on the platforms native thread handle (which differs per platform). Since they are deprecated, they might as well not do anything at all, or yield undefined behaviour, because the native functions they are trying to call no longer work or exist.